# Organizing mirror pairs

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, mirror-symmetry, fukaya-category

At a maximally vague and naive level, mirror symmetry asks the following question: given a complex manifold $(X, I)$, is there a symplectic manifold $(M, \omega)$ and an equivalence between the category of coherent sheaves on $(X,I),$ with morphisms given by something like Ext groups, and the Fukaya category of $(M, \omega),$ with morphisms given by something like the Floer cohomology groups.

I don't want to get into any of the multitudes of (derived) technicalities, and even if I did I wouldn't be able to.

So, let's assume we have some agreed upon definition of the relevant (derived) categories of coherent sheaves and Lagrangian sub-manifolds under consideration.

Then, we can ponder the existence of a category $\mathcal{M}$ whose objects are triples $\{(X,I), (M, \omega), F \}$ where $(X,I)$ is a complex manifold, $(M, \omega)$ is a symplectic manifold, and $F$ is an equivalence of the relevant categories realizing the requirements of (homological) mirror symmetry.

I would be tempted to call this the category of mirror pairs, but I have no idea what a reasonable notion of morphisms in this category should be, has anyone considered this question in any particular context?

I expect it's not a totally empty question, since even in many nice situations, there is no unique assignment of a mirror to a given, say, Calabi-Yau manifold.

Now, however the category $\mathcal{M}$ is defined, at least on objects there is an obvious forgetful assignment to pairs $\{(X,I), (M,\omega)\}.$  Whether this is a functor of course depends on the notion of morphisms in $\mathcal{M},$ and a further choice of morphisms in the category of such pairs of complex and symplectic manifolds.

Nonetheless, it seems to me that the naive, but ultimate, goal of mirror symmetry is to understand the essential image of this conjectural functor.  Are there any toy situations where one can make the above outline reasonably precise?

I appreciate any comments, and thank you for reading.